# How to apply mutliple filter condition for order API during rest call

Tags: rest, shopify

I am using the Order API provided by Shopify for my application. I have the requirement to get those orders whose fulfillment status is either partial or shipped.In the rest url I have tried the below format but nothing has worked. Where I am making the mistake.Please suggest some thing.

https://teststore.myshopify.com/admin/orders.xml?updated_at_min=2014-07-17%2005:00:57-04:00&fulfillment_status=shipped&fulfillment_status=partial

This is giving only the partial shipped orders.

https://teststore.myshopify.com/admin/orders.xml?updated_at_min=2014-07-17%2005:00:57-04:00&fulfillment_status=shipped|partial

This is giving all orders(unshipped,partial,shipped)

What will be the correct format to resolve my problem

Thanks

Utpal Maity

Comment: What does the Shopify API documentation say about how to use the parameter?

Comment: @Tichodroma In Shopify documentation  there is no sample format for multiple filter so I have tried the above format based on standrad found in web but they are not workinh. You can find the documentation in the below link.  http://docs.shopify.com/api/order#index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only filter by one fulfillment_status at the time.

> https://teststore.myshopify.com/admin/orders.xml?updated_at_min=2014-07-17%2005:00:57-04:00&fulfillment_status=shipped&fulfillment_status=partial

In this case, you get only partial because since you specify the same param twice, the first param get overwritten by the second one.

> https://teststore.myshopify.com/admin/orders.xml?updated_at_min=2014-07-17%2005:00:57-04:00&fulfillment_status=shipped|partial

In that case you are filter for "shipped|partial" literally, and since its not a valid status, shopify will ignore the parameter.

You'll have to do two request, one for shipped and another for partial.

Answer (score 2):

Using query you can apply multiple filters on Order API using rest calls:

For example: 
https://test.myshopify.com/admin/api/2019-10/orders.json?query=financial_status:refunded OR financial_status:partially_refunded

Comment: It is not working for me,I have to get orders with financial status as paid and partial refunded